# Handout Mode in Beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I'm currently helping to make some course notes for a new course at my university. One feature the lecturer would like is to be able to have a handout version of the notes with parts hidden for the students to fill in.

When making the Beamer slides, this is fairly straightforward as I can set up the handout mode so that certain content is hidden but the slides are still there (albeit blank). However, they would also like this in article form as they have had experiences with some students in the past expressing that they would like this feature in the article form of the slides.

Is there a way that I can hide content using the beamerarticle package such that there is blank space left where that content would normally be? I was thinking beamerswitch could help, but I've had no luck.

Sorry for not including any LaTeX code, but I think this is more of a general question rather than one that needs a specific example provided. However if what I have described is not clear then I can definitely edit to include one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide content in article mode just the same way it works in handout:

```
%\documentclass{beamer}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc \alt<presentation>{dddd}{\phantom{dddd}} abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```